# Error parsing json: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 with loadGeoJson

Tags: javascript, json, api, maps

I took back a assignement from an intern at work, and I don't know what he did, but I think he messed up the website we're working on. It is build on Wordpress, and I'm trying to build a store locator with Google Maps without any Wordpress plugin, but by using this method : https://developers.google.com/maps/solutions/store-locator/simple-store-locator

I tried this tutorial on a single project and everything worked fine. But when I try to integrate it in the main website, I get the Error parsing stores.json: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

```js
    map.data.loadGeoJson('stores.json', {idPropertyName: 'storeid'});
```

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [{
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [-0.1428115,
        51.5125168
      ]
    },
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
      "category": "patisserie",
      "hours": "10am - 6pm",
      "description": "Modern twists on classic pastries. We're part of a larger chain of patisseries and cafes.",
      "name": "Josie's Patisserie Mayfair",
      "phone": "+44 20 1234 5678",
      "storeid": "01"
    }
  },
    {
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [-2.579623,
          51.452251
        ]
      },
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "category": "patisserie",
        "hours": "10am - 6pm",
        "description": "Come and try our award-winning cakes and pastries. We're part of a larger chain of patisseries and cafes.",
        "name": "Josie's Patisserie Bristol",
        "phone": "+44 117 121 2121",
        "storeid": "02"
      }
    },
    {
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          1.273459,
          52.638072
        ]
      },
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "category": "patisserie",
        "hours": "10am - 6pm",
        "description": "Whatever the occasion, whether it's a birthday or a wedding, Josie's Patisserie has the perfect treat for you. We're part of a larger chain of patisseries and cafes.",
        "name": "Josie's Patisserie Norwich",
        "phone": "+44 1603 123456",
        "storeid": "03"
      }
    },
    {
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [-1.9912838,
          50.8000418
        ]
      },
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "category": "patisserie",
        "hours": "10am - 6pm",
        "description": "A gourmet patisserie that will delight your senses. We're part of a larger chain of patisseries and cafes.",
        "name": "Josie's Patisserie Wimborne",
        "phone": "+44 1202 343434",
        "storeid": "04"
      }
    },
    {
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [-2.985933,
          53.408899
        ]
      },
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "category": "patisserie",
        "hours": "10am - 6pm",
        "description": "Spoil yourself or someone special with our classic pastries. We're part of a larger chain of patisseries and cafes.",
        "name": "Josie's Patisserie Liverpool",
        "phone": "+44 151 444 4444",
        "storeid": "05"
      }
    },
    {
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [-1.689423,
          52.632469
        ]
      },
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "category": "patisserie",
        "hours": "10am - 6pm",
        "description": "Come and feast your eyes and tastebuds on our delicious pastries and cakes. We're part of a larger chain of patisseries and cafes.",
        "name": "Josie's Patisserie Tamworth",
        "phone": "+44 5555 55555",
        "storeid": "06"
      }
    },
    {
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [-3.155305,
          51.479756
        ]
      },
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "category": "patisserie",
        "hours": "10am - 6pm",
        "description": "Josie's Patisserie is family-owned, and our delectable pastries, cakes, and great coffee are renowed. We're part of a larger chain of patisseries and cafes.",
        "name": "Josie's Patisserie Cardiff",
        "phone": "+44 29 6666 6666",
        "storeid": "07"
      }
    },
    {
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [-0.725019,
          52.668891
        ]
      },
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "category": "cafe",
        "hours": "8am - 9:30pm",
        "description": "Oakham's favorite spot for fresh coffee and delicious cakes. We're part of a larger chain of patisseries and cafes.",
        "name": "Josie's Cafe Oakham",
        "phone": "+44 7777 777777",
        "storeid": "08"
      }
    },
    {
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [-2.477653,
          53.735405
        ]
      },
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "category": "cafe",
        "hours": "8am - 9:30pm",
        "description": "Enjoy freshly brewed coffe, and home baked cakes in our homely cafe. We're part of a larger chain of patisseries and cafes.",
        "name": "Josie's Cafe Blackburn",
        "phone": "+44 8888 88888",
        "storeid": "09"
      }
    },
    {
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [-0.211363,
          51.108966
        ]
      },
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "category": "cafe",
        "hours": "8am - 9:30pm",
        "description": "A delicious array of pastries with many flavours, and fresh coffee in an snug cafe. We're part of a larger chain of patisseries and cafes.",
        "name": "Josie's Cafe Crawley",
        "phone": "+44 1010 101010",
        "storeid": "10"
      }
    },
    {
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [-0.123559,
          50.832679
        ]
      },
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "category": "cafe",
        "hours": "8am - 9:30pm",
        "description": "Grab a freshly brewed coffee, a decadent cake and relax in our idyllic cafe. We're part of a larger chain of patisseries and cafes.",
        "name": "Josie's Cafe Brighton",
        "phone": "+44 1313 131313",
        "storeid": "11"
      }
    },
    {
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [-3.319575,
          52.517827
        ]
      },
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "category": "cafe",
        "hours": "8am - 9:30pm",
        "description": "Come in and unwind at this idyllic cafe with fresh coffee and home made cakes. We're part of a larger chain of patisseries and cafes.",
        "name": "Josie's Cafe Newtown",
        "phone": "+44 1414 141414",
        "storeid": "12"
      }
    },
    {
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          1.158167,
          52.071634
        ]
      },
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "category": "cafe",
        "hours": "8am - 9:30pm",
        "description": "Fresh coffee and delicious cakes in an snug cafe. We're part of a larger chain of patisseries and cafes.",
        "name": "Josie's Cafe Ipswich",
        "phone": "+44 1717 17171",
        "storeid": "13"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: What does your browser's Network dev console say is the response when your app tries to request stores.json?

Comment: it says status 301 and type text/html, while in the working demo it says status 200 and type xhr. I've discovered that in the demo, the Request URL is the correct file path to the json file, while in the actual project, the Request URL is the Wordpress permalink. I believe the problem is there, but I really don't know how to fix this

Comment: 301 is the code for Moved Permanently; it means the URL you're making a call to needs to be redirected. If you don't see that call followed by a 200-esque call, you'll have to replace the URL you use in the code with the one that the 301 call says to redirect to in its Location response header.